# Build Condition - "Contains" needed

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I am currently trying to create a new jenkins server and transfer over all the previous jobs from the old server. One error I am running into is on my old server, in the run condition, I am able to specify with the tag "Contains" but in my new server, I dont see this option. Below are two pictures to clarify what I am speaking about. I am quite new to Jenkins and would appreciate any help, thanks!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question to ask is, "what is the version of the [Conditional Build Step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep), [run-condition](https://plugins.jenkins.io/run-condition) and [token macro](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro) plugin on each instance?" That will probably explain the differences.

As "Contains" does not exist in the latest release, it was likely renamed or dropped.  You can probably use "regular expression match" as a substitute if I were to guess.